# Check if value exists in the database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I would like to check if the value of `$_POST['email']` exists in my table. If not, new values should be added to the database.

```
$member = new Members();
$member->setEmail($_POST['email']);
$member->setName($_POST['vorname']);
$member->setPassword(password_hash($_POST['pw1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($member);

$get_email = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')->find($_POST['email']);

if (!$get_email) {
    $em->flush();
    echo 'User registered.';
}
else {
    echo 'User already exists.';
}
```

In this case the user always gets registered.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method `findBy()` which gets an associative array  "field" => "value"` as a param.

So in you example (assuming email is stored in column named `email`):

```
$get_email = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')->findBy(array('email' => $_POST['email']));
```

Comment: Isn't it `findBy()` instead of `find()`, when you're passing an array like that?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are absolutely right. `findBy` works like charm for me!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missread OP's post. Corrected, thank you @MagnusEriksson for notice

Answer (score 0):

find($id)

findBy(array())

findOneBy(array())

I think you should not confuse the three methods